# FlowPlayer on Chrome not recognizing Adobe Flash when the site loads for the first time

Tags: google-chrome, flash, flowplayer

A few of our clients who use our websites to play videos online have been getting this message recently in Chrome.

We use the Flash version of FlowPlayer (v3.2.18) to play videos. This has been working for a long time. Only recently this message is appearing.

I know Chrome has been deprecating Flash for a long time. The message appearing over the player is coming from flowplayer.js when it doesn't recognize the plugin been installed in Chrome although it is. Is there any workaround for this?

Message:

> Flash version 10,1 or greater is required
>
> You have no flash plugin installed
>
> Download latest version from here

Comment: Show a link to your example page showing this issue. In general it's enough to put your Flash app (_SWF_ file) inside an `embed` tag. See [**example code**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed). Replace that swf link with your own link to the swf that came bundled with FlowPlayer files.

Comment: Nominated for reopening. While not 100% clear from the text, this is a question from a _web developer_ regarding FlowPlayer deployed on a website _they control_ - not from a Chrome end-user.

Comment: @Prithvi You may want to reformulate the question to make what I said in the comment above more obvious.

Comment: @Xan Yes you are right. I have already edited the question. Looks like it is still on hold. How else do I put that question? Basically flash version of FlowPlayer is not working on Chrome whenever the site using the player loads for the first time. Once I click allow on the alert box that comes up on Chrome, it starts working. I've got the answer below with the reason.

Comment: I saw you edit the title, but _that's far from enough_. Please edit the question body in a way that makes it clear you're not asking as a browser user, but as a web developer that controls the site in question.

Comment: @Xan I've updated the body now. Let me know how it sounds now. It is a little bit weird to edit that after I've got an answer anyway :)

Comment: I've improved it further; a consensus of 3 (or 5, I don't remember) votes is needed to reopen it, so I can't help further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused because Chrome is phasing out Flash in favor of HTML5.

Flash is still supported in Chrome but the user needs to **manually enable flash for each site**. Why a site requires to manually activated or not is based on something called site engagement. Basically, the more you visit a site the higher the this index is, you can check your values if you input this url : **chrome://site-engagement**  .But please note that the plan from Google is that in few months (by Oct 2017) everybody will require to activate flash for each site even in the sites with highest indexes.

Google is doing this to force people to adopt HTML5. More info here:

https://blog.chromium.org/2016/12/roll-out-plan-for-html5-by-default.html

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/flash-roadmap#TOC-HTML5-By-Default-Target:-Chrome-55---Dec-2016-

Your option here (in addition to manually enable flash for the site, or use other browser :-) ) is to use Flowplayer 7 (or any other HTML5 player). The lastest versions of Flowplayer offers an html5 video player with flash fallback support.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already looked into the HTML5 version of FlowPlayer. There weren't any plugins supported by the HTML5 version before. The Flash version was used because it has a plugin for pseudo streaming which allows seeking videos without the need to configure anything in the server.

The plugin called hlsjs enables seeking while playing the video. But it requires the video streams must be served with a cross domain policy (CORS) allowing GET requests.

The plugin works on my local (with errors on seeking). Will have to find a way to make that work when hosted in the server.